# Комментирование на WebStrom

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

Я люблю оставлять закрывающие комментарии для красоты кода

```
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Недавно я перешел с *Visual Studio* code на *WebStrom*.

Когда я делал комментарий в новой строке в VScode это выглядело так:

```
    </div>
    <!-- -->
</div>
```

А в WebStrom выглядит так:

```
    </div>
<!--     -->
</div>
```

То есть когда я пишу комментарий в новой строке, WB комментирует все пустоты (хотя я нажимал только Enter, табуляцию не использовал).

**Можно ли как то настроить WB, чтобы комментарии на новой строке выглядели так:**

```
    </div>
    <!-- -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте `Ctrl+Shift+/` вместо `Ctrl+/`

```html
    </div>
    <!---->
</div>
```

Настройки: `Ctrl+Alt+S` > Code Style > HTML > Code Generation